# Pra que serve o "self "?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando Python para complementar meus programas em Nodejs.

Porém por que em Python, uma linguagem que preza a velocidade no desenvolvimento e facilidade no código, é utilizado o self?

Exemplo bem simples do uso do self

```
class ButtonPerson(Button, Person):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Person.__init__(self)
        Button.__init__(self, "Pessoa: " + name)
        self.set_name(name)
```

**Não é redundante?**

Comment: [*Explicit is better than implicit*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python)

Comment: @bfavaretto achei legal essa filosofia, mas ainda não vejo o pq do self...rs

Comment: Pra eu entender melhor a pergunta: como você escreveria algo com essa mesma estrutura em JS, já que você disse que usa node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embora em outro idioma, esta pergunta foi respondida [no próprio STO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self). Então fiz apenas uma adptação:

A razão pela qual você precisa usar o self é porque o Python não usa a sintaxe @ para se referir aos atributos de instâncias.

O time do Python decidiu fazer métodos de uma maneira que faz com que a instância a qual o método pertence seja passada automaticamente, mas não recebida automaticamente: O primeiro parâmetro de um método é a instância em que o método é chamado.

Isso faz com que os métodos sejam inteiramente iguais às funções, e **deixa o nome real para ser usado, a cargo do usuário/desenvolvedor** (embora a palavra `self` seja a convenção e a maioria das pessoas torcerão o nariz se voce usar uma outra palavra qualquer).

> Editada
>   Exemplo evitando o `self` (não torçam o nariz!) :-)
>   Obs. Rodei em um terminal (local) python 3, no [repl.it](https://repl.it/) não foi aceito, exige o `self`

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(this, msg):     
        this.msg = msg

    @property    
    def bar(this): 
        return 'Hello '+this.msg

foo = Foo('bar')
foo.bar
'Hello bar'
```

`self` Não tem nada de especial para o código, é apenas mais um objeto.

O desenvolvedores do Python poderiam ter optado por outra estrategia para distiguir "nomes normais" de atributos -- Sintaxe especial como o Ruby, ou requerer declarações como o C++ e Java ou, talvez, qualquer outra coisa diferente-- SQN.

Python tem como um dos pilares de sua filosofia a determinação de fazer as coisas da forma mais explícitas possível, embora, obviamente esse objetivo nem sempre possa ser atingindo.

Em consequencia desse objetivo é que voce precisa do `self`, para fazer uma atribuição a um atributo de instancia, é necessário **explicitar** a que instancia atribuir, `self` informa que a atribuição é a si mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Uma comparação que talvez te ajude a entender, é pensar no `self` como se fosse o `this` do java/C#. Que não fica explicito na implementação mas também aponta para o próprio objeto.

No caso do python, quando você chama um método de uma classe ele automaticamente passa esse parâmetro na primeira posição.

O primeiro parâmetro de uma classe, recebe uma instância desse mesmo objeto e serve para acessar atributos e métodos do mesmo objeto.

---

Gostaria de deixar claro que não há nenhuma obrigatoriedade de se fazer assim podemos usar qualquer outro nome para o parâmetro.

> Costuma-se chamar o primeiro parâmetro de self porque a maioria dos
>   programadores Python já reconhece esse nome como o nome do objeto a
>   ser invocado no método; ademais, esse é o padrão especificado pela
>   PEP-8. Por isso mesmo, via de regra é melhor utilizar self como o nome
>   do primeiro parâmetro dos métodos.